# In Rails, how can I display ip addresses from a db stored as int8, and not inet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

IP addresses are stored in my db (I have not control over this) as int8, not inet. I know how to work around this when I query using psql.

## How can I accomplish this in rails?

For example, using psql if I query as so I get the int8 answer back.;

```
SELECT ip_src, ip_dst from iphdr ;
   ip_src   |   ip_dst   
------------+------------
 2886730039 | 2887777037
```

But if I use '0.0.0.0'::inet + ip_src as ipsrc,'0.0.0.0'::inet + ip_dst as ipdst I get the ip addresses;

```
SELECT '0.0.0.0'::inet + ip_src as ipsrc,'0.0.0.0'::inet + ip_dst as ipdst from iphdr ;
      ipsrc      |     ipdst      
-----------------+----------------
 172.16.1.55     | 172.31.251.13
```

This may help show you how I'm querying the addresses.

In my application_helper I have;

```
  def get_attacker_ip(sid)
    IpsIphdr.where('sid =?', sid).first.ip_src
  end

  def get_target_ip(sid)
    IpsIphdr.where('sid =?', sid).first.ip_dst
  end
```

In my controller;

```
  def ips_dashboard

    @event = IpsEvent.find 1, 7

  end
```

In my view;

```
    <th>Timestamp</th>
    <th>Sensor Name</th>
    <th>Signature Name</th>
    <th>Signature Class</th>
    <th>Attacker</th>
    <th>Target</th>

  </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='timestamp'><%= @event.timestamp %></td>
        <td class='sensor_name'><%=  get_hostname(@event.sid) %></td>
        <td class='sig_name'><%=  get_sig_name(@event.signature) %></td>
        <td class='sig_class'><%=  get_sig_class_id(@event.signature) %></td>
        <td class='attacker'><%=  get_attacker_ip(@event.sid) %></td>
        <td class='target'><%=  get_target_ip(@event.sid) %></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get_attacker_ip(@event.sid).
  to_s(16).      # convert to hex
  rjust(8, '0'). # pad with leading zeroes
  scan(/.{2}/).  # split into 2-char chunks
  map(&:hex).    # convert each chunk to base-10
  join('.')      # join with dots
```

Comment: Thats pretty impressive, but I get `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)'. This is what I used <%=  get_sig_class_id(@event.signature).to_s(16).rjust(8,'0').scan(/.{2}/).map(&:hex).join('.') %>

Comment: I had to add it in the application helper.`IpsIphdr.where('sid =?', sid).first.ip_src.to_s(16).rjust(8,'0').scan(/.{2}/).map(&:hex).join('.')`

Comment: Moving the code to the helper didn't do anything. `get_sig_class_id` didn't return a `Fixnum` representing an IP address. Only `Fixnum#to_s` accepts an argument, that's where your error came from.

Comment: Your right, I put it in the wrong spot, one line above where it needed to go. Thanks again!